# 'int' object is not subscriptable. Listas en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas tardes, estoy haciendo un programa sencillo a modo didáctico que se encarga de llegar a un numero X con ciertas operaciones. 
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
##Los numeros de la persona
numeroP1 = [0,0,0,0]
numeroP2 = [0,0,0,0]
##Los numeros de la computadora
numeroC1 = [0,0,0,0]
numeroC2 = [0,0,0,0]
numeroC3 = [0,0,0,0]

primerNumero = int(input("Ingresa un numero de 4 digitos "))


if primerNumero >= 1111 and primerNumero <= 9999: ##len() no funciona para int
    numeroP1[0] = primerNumero[0]
    numeroP1[1] = primerNumero[1]
    numeroP1[2] = primerNumero[2]
    numeroP1[3] = primerNumero[3]

    print ("El primer numero es: " , numeroP1[0])
    print ("El segundo  numero es: " , numeroP1[1])
    print ("El tercer numero es: " , numeroP1[2])
    print ("El cuarto numero es: " , numeroP1[3])

    numeroC2[0] = 9 - numeroP1[0]
    print ("La resta da: " , numeroC2[0])



else:
    print ("No has ingresado un numero de 4 digitos")
```

Necesito lograr que en numeroC2[0] se guarde y se muestre el resultado de (9 - numeroP1[0]). Es aquí donde me salta el error "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable". El mismo se encuentra en esta linea

```
numeroP1[0] = primerNumero[0]
```

Probe de esta forma pero tampoco funciono:

```
numeroP1[0] = int(primerNumero[0])
```

Comment: Cuidado que en ese while tienes un ciclo infinito. a mi parecer. debería ser if

Comment: Sisi, lo acabo de notar, gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que estás tratando el entero `primerNumero` como una lista. Para coger los dígitos, debes utilizar el módulo y divisiones enteras entre 10.

```
numeroP1[3] = primerNumero % 10
numeroP1[2] = primerNumero // 10 % 10
numeroP1[1] = primerNumero // 100 % 10
numeroP1[0] = primerNumero // 1000 % 10
```

Comment: Perfecto. El problema ahora es que me arroja decimales:
El primer numero es:  1.234
El segundo  numero es:  2.34
El tercer numero es:  3.4000000000000057
El cuarto numero es:  4
La resta da:  7.766

Comment: Se me había pasado. En Python 3.x, la división entera es `//` en lugar de `/`.

Comment: Funciona perfecto! Gracias! Podrías explicarme breve-mente porque con los módulos y la división se soluciona mi problema? Saludos y gracias de nuevo!

Comment: El módulo devuelve el resto de dividir entre un número. Si aplicamos el módulo 10 a cualquier número, nos devolverá su último dígito: `1253 % 10 = 3`, `9740 % 10 = 0`. Si dividimos un número entre 10 y nos quedamos con la parte entera, estamos eliminando el último dígito: `1252 / 10 = 125`, `9740 / 10 = 974`. Si en lugar de dividir entre 10 dividimos entre 100, 1000, ... estamos eliminando los 2, 3, ... últimos dígitos. Así, para el cuarto dígito cogemos el módulo, para el tercero dividimos entre 10 y el módulo, para el segundo entre 100 y el módulo, y para el primero entre 1000 y el módulo.

Comment: Muy bueno Jose! Bastante ingenioso e inteligente de tu parte. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta anterior es valida, además tienes la opción de convertir a `array` el entero ingresado mediante `listas` de la siguiente forma

```
if primerNumero >= 1111 and primerNumero <= 9999: ##len() no funciona para int
    lst = [int(i) for i in str(primerNumero)]##cnvert input to list
    numeroP1= lst ##asigna la lista a NumeroP1
    print ("El primer numero es: " , numeroP1[0])
    print ("El segundo  numero es: " , numeroP1[1])
```